# How to add a flat amount discount on an oppty/quote?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have a very complicated oppty, that eventually, needs to get a discount of XX dollars.

I have the SF quotes module installed, thinking I can modify the fields there. I can play with each lines % field, and adjust the final with an extra "mock-discount" product. But I prefer not too.

How can I give a finite amount discount to an oppty?

Answer (score 2):

The "mock discount" product is the correct way to handle a flat rate discount. Any other means of adding a discount (i.e. via custom fields, etc) will result in incorrect forecasting and reporting.

Comment: The problem with that is that it effects the Average price of the product sold in this oppty. (it might be a small % overall, but it has an effect).